# here.com API oAuth credentials

Tags: api, rest, oauth, token, here-api

I am testing the here.com location REST API. I have setup REST oAuth credentials in the developer portal and have successfully requested an oAuth token via Postman. When I try to use the token in the fuel prices API, I receive the error:

```
        "These credentials do not authorize access"
```

oAuth POST request:

```
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="wD7h-u8jE03c0jRu2m4XBQ",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256",oauth_timestamp="1600812281",oauth_nonce="npygZT9FJ9f",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="fM6AsYnp9jKHlY6ESyKwUwqIHQik4ad6spUeiWAh2ag%3D"
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.5
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 169bc9d1-5ef6-46e6-aab8-d0d11d048d15
Host: account.api.here.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 29
Request Body
Response Headers
Date: Tue, 22 Sep 2020 22:04:42 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 911
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
X-Request-ID: REQ-b62ce9c9-eddd-4c03-8e67-186a56c031b1
Cache-Control: no-store
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Response-Time: 53
X-Correlation-ID: e0c4b375-8fed-4b70-be56-2d78c6f37e18
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: master-only
Response Body

{"access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzUxMiIsImN0eSI6IkpXVCIsImlzcyI6IkhFUkUiLCJhaWQiOiJaVjhwbGFFWDdRekd2VUNXbUdGbiIsImlhdCI6MTYwMDgxMjI4MiwiZXhwIjoxNjAwODk4NjgyLCJraWQiOiJqMSJ9.ZXlKaGJHY2lPaUprYVhJaUxDSmxibU1pT2lKQk1qVTJRMEpETFVoVE5URXlJbjAuLk8tRDdJQm9Mdzk5b1dxejJ1Vmx0Y1EuSmlYUmMwV0N6cVFUbVFicmhNaDNONkFENVJ6YWVMenFfdWpOWVZlekgyQ2dvbERLcFFEcUNrODFlMWFoMmlZZXZXZzFHNVhDZUtsZEc0WXhwX0pSU2lPaUkxUUNMRWZhakFscEFHQjdta0JLdjktbXllXzlqeDFGbzM2T0tUaDRuNXdxWEZVbnhtMkRYOHRQYjVZZUZBLl9qUlE0NU9PTmd3ZHpwY1c4cUxJck5hRmhYcTVLM1hzMHZzYl85MTFtVVU.R62C1fZVxt29r0VPA9jYVdWRbqO5lFH0yNtomCSxAnpTaHf4ed215u7o21RnwEjy-Dl2vgCAP8Oc4xNN4uoi2ImzwRtdtDU8y3wqOYHakRXyuP5PdvKejjpB1MAmw8TYVQkTfrfsgG972wo2g_0jx3VzmcOXJSl8wHU5y3rdEgNG-vDvV1wlJwQDX6ZKc2FLSzk1yEv9NSsAYur21PrnBfMImaenvGzEh1J747HmUfrHOPr-wRPvTQE4GNiOf4hWKXJrnPwpg85S_S8EZgGqlRVfNQ4V2g_7LfH1ZjFxiZrd8oZFPbnAI1ihDSBqaTy04HXotXsyp92YzDhVHwDavw","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":86399}
```

Get request to fuel REST API

```
GET https://fuel-v2.cc.ls.api.here.com/fuel/stations.json?prox=36.0029435,%20-78.9059841&fueltype=1
Request Headers
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzUxMiIsImN0eSI6IkpXVCIsImlzcyI6IkhFUkUiLCJhaWQiOiJaVjhwbGFFWDdRekd2VUNXbUdGbiIsImlhdCI6MTYwMDgxMjI4MiwiZXhwIjoxNjAwODk4NjgyLCJraWQiOiJqMSJ9.ZXlKaGJHY2lPaUprYVhJaUxDSmxibU1pT2lKQk1qVTJRMEpETFVoVE5URXlJbjAuLk8tRDdJQm9Mdzk5b1dxejJ1Vmx0Y1EuSmlYUmMwV0N6cVFUbVFicmhNaDNONkFENVJ6YWVMenFfdWpOWVZlekgyQ2dvbERLcFFEcUNrODFlMWFoMmlZZXZXZzFHNVhDZUtsZEc0WXhwX0pSU2lPaUkxUUNMRWZhakFscEFHQjdta0JLdjktbXllXzlqeDFGbzM2T0tUaDRuNXdxWEZVbnhtMkRYOHRQYjVZZUZBLl9qUlE0NU9PTmd3ZHpwY1c4cUxJck5hRmhYcTVLM1hzMHZzYl85MTFtVVU.R62C1fZVxt29r0VPA9jYVdWRbqO5lFH0yNtomCSxAnpTaHf4ed215u7o21RnwEjy-Dl2vgCAP8Oc4xNN4uoi2ImzwRtdtDU8y3wqOYHakRXyuP5PdvKejjpB1MAmw8TYVQkTfrfsgG972wo2g_0jx3VzmcOXJSl8wHU5y3rdEgNG-vDvV1wlJwQDX6ZKc2FLSzk1yEv9NSsAYur21PrnBfMImaenvGzEh1J747HmUfrHOPr-wRPvTQE4GNiOf4hWKXJrnPwpg85S_S8EZgGqlRVfNQ4V2g_7LfH1ZjFxiZrd8oZFPbnAI1ihDSBqaTy04HXotXsyp92YzDhVHwDavw
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.5
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: d5d3944f-4c5c-44ef-8eb4-0202a4d669c0
Host: fuel-v2.cc.ls.api.here.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Response Headers
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Tue, 22 Sep 2020 22:11:15 GMT
Server: nginx-clojure
Vary: Accept-Encoding,Origin
X-HERE-RESPONSE-TIME: 0
Content-Length: 99
Connection: keep-alive
Response Body
{"Type":"Forbidden","Message":["These credentials do not authorize access"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, currently the Freemium plan doesn't have an access to Connected vehicle services https://developer.here.com/documentation#cvs

On https://developer.here.com/documentation/fuel-prices/dev_guide/topics/credentials.html you can see:

There are two kinds of credentials:

- Development credentials - these credentials are for evaluation and
  development. To obtain your development credentials, **contact your
  customer/sales representative** and sign the appropriate evaluation
  agreements.
- Production credentials - these credentials are for commercial
  deployment. To obtain your commercial credentials, sign the
  appropriate commercial agreements. You must have completed all
  testing, be ready for deployment and have signed a commercial
  agreement before you apply for production credentials.

You can also read this Knowledge Base [What other HERE Location Services limits apply to my Freemium or Pro plan?](https://knowledge.here.com/csm_kb?id=public_kb_csm_details&number=KB0016408) - there the information about Connected vehicle services will be added later.